# Facebook incentive to like page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, x-facebook-platform

We are working on ideas to provide an extra incentive for people to become and stay fans of a company Facebook page (on top of truly being a fan of course). some sort of loyalty program, if you will.

We are wondering if this is a technically and Facebook Platform policy-wise feasible idea.

The loyalty program would be an app that you can log in to with Facebook and that will see if you like a certain company page and since what date.

Is this something that be read using Object Likes?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/likes

If possible, we would like this information to raffle prizes among users that have liked that company page a certain amount of time. Is this something that would be against the Facebook Platform Policies?

https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Section 4.5 says: "Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions."

It's not entirely clear if a setup as descrivbed above counts as "entering a promotion on your app's Page"

Any input on this would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can only read the Page likes with `/me/likes`, and you need the `user_likes` permission. You are not allowed to incentivize liking a Page. Like Gating is not allowed and you will not get `user_likes` approved for that.

Meaning, it´s not allowed and not even possible to reward users in any way for liking a Page. Users must like a Page only because they really want to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This would seem to be the case, following the letter of the Platform Policy. Still, the idea would be to reward long time fans, more than acquiring new ones or tricking them into liking the page.

Comment: definititely still not allowed, it does not matter how long they liked the page. where would be the limit? 1 week? one year? it is not allowed to reward users in any way for liking the page, even if you only reward long term users it would still be incentivizing. i could like the page right now only because i will get something later > not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question! but actually I see no violation in doing so ... as I understand from your Question, it's not like you're buying the likes, but you're rewarding your fans - some sort of loyalty program - you also maintain your current fans and nothing wrong in that!

But seriously I understand your concerns about getting rejected by Facebook .. and I can't confirm you can pass the Facebook Review with this scenario!

So my advice to you is "try to build a prototype and submit it for reviewing" or "try to contact anyone from Facebook Support Team and validate your scenario with them".

Please share the updates with us :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We think it's an interesting question, since it's not directly like-gating content, but in the end it seems like incentivising something other than "to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place."

Is there another way to contact the Facebook Support Team, besides prototyping an app and submitting it for review? When using the Direct Support optin and clicking 'Ask a question' it tells me: "You don't have any remaining questions to use this service. Please contact your account manager for further assistance."